# Basic express hello world

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code in node.js which is very basic express code but I can't get it to work. when I visit localhost/, it gives me text "Cannot GET /". It should display Hello world.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});
```

Comment: which port are you using to run express ? you can check the console where you are running it.

Comment: after specifying the port by using app.listen(3000); localhost:3000/ throws error unable to connect

Comment: have you started the app by running `node app.js` ? (guessing app.js is where your code is).

Answer (score 0):

do you open port?

The server must open the port.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server open");
});
```

If listen method called by app, Prepares to receive the client's response to the port passed as the first argument.

U can execute this code.

**node app.js** OR **supervisor app.js** OR **forever start app.js** ETC